# Ember Data: convert ISO date string to date

Tags: javascript, datetime, serialization, ember.js, isodate

The [Ember Documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_serialize) on serializers mentions that date attributes are parsed somehow:

> By default, attributes are passed through as-is, unless you specified an attribute type (DS.attr('date'))

However, when I return an ISO-style date of the form `2014-08-13 14:37:53`, my Ember inspector shows that my date attributes are simply empty objects.  I've [played with manually deserializing these](http://sapandiwakar.in/serializingdeserializing-dates-tofrom-iso-8601-format-ember-data/) with a custom serializer, but I'd like to use the default Ember Data method if possible.

Am I missing something in the docs?